# Distribution of norm over projected unit vectors

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics, norms, gaussian

I am interested in the distribution of norms of projected unit vectors, for a particular class of projections. We first draw an $n$-dimensonal unit vector $v=X/||X||$ where $X=(X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n)$ with $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$. Now consider a linear transformation $B\in\mathbb{R}^{(n/q)\times n}$ which shortens $v$ in the following manner: it buckets (as a sum) the first $q$ entries together, then the next $q$ entries, and so forth. As an example, if $n=4$ and $q=2$, then $Bv=(X_1+X_2, X_3+X_4)$.

> Question: Assuming $q$ divides $n$, what is the pdf of $||Bv||^2$?

### Current approach

The norm-squared will appear as the following:
$$||Bv||^2=\frac{(X_1+\cdots+X_q)^2}{||X||^2}+\frac{(X_{q+1}+\cdots+X_{2q})^2}{||X||^2}+\cdots+\frac{(X_{n-{q+1}}+\cdots+X_{n})^2}{||X||^2}$$

I believe that each of these $n/q$ terms follows $q$ times a $\textrm{Beta}(1/2,(n-1)/2)$ variate but the dependency between them seems difficult to resolve. Numerical simulation has shown me that the density beyond $\sqrt{q}$ is thin and it's clear that the support must vanish beyond $q$ just by considering the singular values of $B$. Any direction (even towards valuable references) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, question has been edited for clarity. You're right, a mistake was made (and edited in the question): consider a more general term $(X)^2/||X||^2$, it is known that its distribution is identical to $(e^{\top}X)^2/||X||^2$, where $e$ is any unit vector. Consider a unit $w$ which kills off all $X_i$ in X except for those contained in one of the terms, we know then that $(e.X)^2/||X||^2$ is identical in distribution to $(w^{\top}X)^2/||X||^2$. The RV $(e.X)^2/||X||^2$ follows a Beta$(1/2,(n−1)/2)$ distribution and scaling by $n/q$ gives us the corrected description.

Comment: It may make sense to rotate in each $q$-dimensional subspace and to reduce it to $q\frac{\|X\|^2}{\|X\|^2+\|Y\|^2}$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal vectors in $\mathbb R^{n/q}$ and $\mathbb R^{n-n/q}$ respectively. The distributions of $\|X\|^2$ and $\|Y\|^2$ are classical and then you can use the independence to get the desired pdf of the ratio by appropriate integration.

Comment: @fedja I had considered this approach, but in some sense was concerned about "independently" rotating these individual subspaces, but since the coordinates in the numerator do not overlap between them, after further thought this is definitely the right approach. If you re-post the above comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @fedja and just to further clarify, your comment verbatim, with no further explanation!